# I get stuck with this integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, partial-fractions

$$\frac{1}{10} \int \frac{3x+20}{x^2+10}dx$$
I was trying to factor out the denominator:
$$\frac{1}{10} \int \frac{3x+20}{x^2+(\sqrt{10})^2}dx$$

$$\frac{1}{10} \int \frac{3x+20}{(x+\sqrt{10})^2-2x\sqrt{10}}dx$$

I was trying to factor the denominator to use partial fractions but failed how should I approach this integral?

Comment: Unless you plan to bring in complex numbers, you can't factor the denominator, because its roots ($\pm\sqrt{10}\mathrm i$) are imaginary. With a quadratic factor with imaginary roots such as this one, you want to complete the square (which you can skip since there's no $x$ term), split the numerator into two terms (as in @LanierFreeman 's answer), and do the first term with a substitution and the second with an arctangent. (If you do bring in complex numbers, then you'll get logarithms instead; an arctangent can be written as a logarithm with complex numbers. But I wouldn't do it that way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to split it into two integrals, one of the form $\int f'/f\,dx$, the other $\int dx/(x^2+a^2)$, which equals $\tfrac1a\tan^{-1}\tfrac xa$:
\begin{align*}
\int\frac{3x+20}{x^2+10}\,dx&=\frac32\int\frac{2x}{x^2+10}\,dx+20\int\frac{dx}{x^2+(\sqrt{10})^2}\\[15pt]
&=\frac32\log(x^2+10)+\frac{20}{\sqrt{10}}\tan^{-1}\Big(\frac x{\sqrt{10}}\Big).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\frac{3x+20}{x^2+10}=\frac{3x}{x^2+10}+\frac{20}{x^2+10}$$

Answer (score 0):

$${\frac{3x+20}{x^2+10}=\frac{\frac{3}2+\sqrt{10}i}{x+\sqrt{10}i}+\frac{\frac{3}2-\sqrt{10}i}{x-\sqrt{10}i}}$$

Lets integrate,

$$\int \frac{3x+20}{x^2+10}{=\int \frac{\frac{3}2+\sqrt{10}i}{x+\sqrt{10}i}+\int \frac{\frac{3}2-\sqrt{10}i}{x-\sqrt{10}i}\\
=\left(\frac{3}2+\sqrt{10}i\right)\ln\left(x+\sqrt{10}i\right)+\left(\frac{3}2-\sqrt{10}i\right)\ln\left(x-\sqrt{10}i\right)+c}$$

Now,
$$\ln\left(x+\sqrt{10}i\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+10}\,e^{i\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{10}}{x}}}\right)=\ln\sqrt{x^2+10} +{i\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{10}}{x}}}\\
\ln\left(x-\sqrt{10}i\right)=\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+10}\,e^{i\arctan{\frac{-\sqrt{10}}{x}}}\right)=\ln\sqrt{x^2+10} -{i\arctan{\frac{\sqrt{10}}{x}}}\\$$

Puting the  values, $$\int \frac{3x+20}{x^2+10}=3\ln\sqrt{x^2+10}-2\sqrt{10}\arctan\frac{\sqrt{10}}{x}+c$$

This is how to "factor the denominator to use partial fractions."